# Php code to convert .xml to .xls(Basically from xmlExcel to Excel spreadsheet)

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way to convert .xml file to .xls using php code?

Answer (score 3):

1) Read in the XML file using `[simplexml_load_file()][1]`

2) Loop through each XML element representing one line item in the XLS file

3) Use `[fputcsv()][2]` to create a comma separated file with the data from step 2

4) Save the file with a .csv extension and it will open in excel.

If you want to create an Excel spreadsheet I think you need to work with COM objects. Not my forté so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno about converting XML to XSL, but in the book [PHP Hacks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101392) there is a hack for generating excel spreadsheets [most of which is available on Google Books](http://books.google.ca/books?id=YZRFk__QcksC&pg=PA207&dq=php+hacks+create+excel+sheet+dynamically&hl=en&ei=eO-0S8f1AoSKlwf9z6Bz&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false), in its chapter on XML no less!

So that would be a good place to start looking if nobody's got the answer here.